# How to share a post on the user's timeline on Facebook and know if he accepted?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I have an Android App using Parse and Facebook SDK.

But all I need is to post a link on the user's timeline and knows if he accepted the post.

I've been through a lot of tutorials and days here on stackoverflow and it seems there is not up to date answers to that.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "accept the post"?

Comment: I pop up a Share Window and the user hits POST. In contrary of hitting the BACK button or CANCEL.